# Are there gender-neutral names in Latin?

Tags: names, gender

Latin has some "epicene nouns", like *canis* "dog", which can be either masculine or feminine: a good dog could be either a *canis bonus* or a *canis bona*, depending on the dog in question.

Are there any epicene names? That is, are there any attested names in Latin that could be used by either a man or a woman, without changing the form at all? (Names like *Julius/Julia* don't count, because the ending has to change along with the gender.)

Comment: Just to clarify, are you specifically asking about *praenomina*, or do you want to include *nomina* and *cognomina* as well?

Comment: @brianpck Any of the three.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I could find two such examples, both *cognomina*.

- **Sulla**: Sulla's daughter was called Cornelia Sulla.
- **Cotta**: Julius Caesar's mother was called [Aurelia Cotta](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aurelia_Cotta), probably daughter of the [Lucius Aurelius Cotta](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lucius_Aurelius_Cotta_(consul_119_BC)) mentioned by Cicero in his *De Natura Deorum*. It belongs to the first declension, as this excerpt shows:

> Est enim et philosophi et pontificis et Cottae de dis immortalibus habere non errantem et vagam ut Academici, sed ut nostri stabilem certamque sententiam.